# Populate ComboBox ExtJS 4.2 using JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, extjs, combobox

I have to populate a ComboBox in ExtJS 4.2 using JSON data received from a php.
Code so far :
DataStore:

```
var Cstates = new Ext.data.Store({
    autoLoad: true,
    url: 'data.php',
    storeId: 'Cstates',
    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
        root: 'state'
    }),
    idProperty: 'abbr',
    fields: ['abbr', 'name']
});
```

ComboBox:

```
{
    xtype: 'combo',
    id: 'cmbState',
    fieldLabel: ' Select state :',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    store: Cstates,
    queryMode: 'local',
    valueField: 'abbr',
    displayField: 'name',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    typeAhead: true,
    emptyText: '* All States',
    forceSelection: true,
    selectOnFocus: true,
    allowBlank: false,
    selectOnTab: true,
    //hidden: true,
    disabled: true
}
```

JSON received:

```
{state:[{"abbr":"E1","name":"EAST1"},{"abbr":"E2","name":"EAST2"}]}
```

Also later I need to populate this combobox with some other value that will be returned in the same format from a php using GET ie data.php?region=EAST.

Comment: so what exactly is the question? Have you tried anything? Did you get any error or something?

Comment: Are you looking at how to reload the `store` from the new url?

Comment: Have tried things like JSONReader too but none worked, the above code ins't populating the combobox, even firebug shows no GET req being fired to the php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the chained combobox working example

```
// first combobox model definition
Ext.define('ArticleMainGroup', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'PWHG', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'PWHG_BEZ', type: 'string'}
    ]
});

// first combobox store definition
var articleMain = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    model: 'ArticleMainGroup',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>dashboard/promotion',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'ArticleMainGroup',
            idProperty: 'PWHG'
        }
    }
});

// second combobox store definition
var articleBase = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    model: 'ArticleBaseGroup',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>dashboard/promotion',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'ArticleBaseGroup',
            idProperty: 'PWG'
        }
    }
});

// first combobox definition
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    fieldLabel: 'ANA MAL GRUBU',
    store: articleMain,
    id: 'art-main-group',
    queryMode: 'local',
    autoSelect: true,
    forceSelection: true,
    triggerAction: 'all',
    inputWidth: 240,
    margin: '5 0 0 0',
    listConfig: { cls: 'combo-dep' },
    valueField: 'PWHG',
    displayField: 'PWHG_BEZ',
    listeners: {
        select: function(combo) {
            Ext.getCmp('art-base-group').setValue("");
                /**
                 * this is the important part
                 * articleBase is a store definition which is bound to second combobox
                 * when we send a parameter by extraParams, the target store using this 
                 * parameter via url string
                 * after that we should re-load the target store by load() method
                 * as a result, target combobox will populate based on this url parameter
                 * like http://localhost/dashboard?maingroup=10
                 */
            articleBase.proxy.extraParams = {'maingroup': combo.getValue()};
            articleBase.load();
        }
    }
}

// second combobox definition
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    fieldLabel: 'MAL GRUBU',
    store: articleBase,
    id: 'art-base-group',
    queryMode: 'local',
    autoSelect: false,
    forceSelection: true,
    triggerAction: 'all',
    editable: false,
    valueField: 'PWG',
    displayField: 'PWG_BEZ',
    inputWidth: 240,
    margin: '10 0 0 0',
    listConfig: { cls: 'combo-dep' },
    listeners: {
        select: function(combo) {
            Ext.getCmp('art-sub-group').setValue("");
            articleSub.proxy.extraParams = {'maingroup': Ext.getCmp('art-main-group').getValue(), 'basegroup': combo.getValue()}
            articleSub.load();
        }
    }
}
```